# WordPress not adding captions to my images

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to add a caption to media I'm adding to my posts but when I insert the image it just inserts the image tag and the caption as 'alt', like so;

```
<img src="url" alt="the caption" />
```

instead of:

```
[caption id="attachment_6" align="alignright" width="300" caption="the caption"]<img src="url" />[/caption]
```

I'm using the latest version of wordpress and the twentythirteen theme.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is related to your theme coding. Try using this shortcode:
[caption width="600" caption="A football video"][embed]http://vimeo.com/14580921[/embed][/caption]

put caption into embed

And try switching to the default theme.

Comment: I tried it, it works. The problem im having is getting wordpress to insert the the shortcode along with the image, right now just the image is inserted.

Comment: [caption id="attachment_6" align="alignright" width="300" caption="The Great Wave"]<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/800px-Great_Wave_off_Kanagawa2-300x205.jpg" alt="Kanagawa" title="The Great Wave" width="300" height="205" class="size-medium wp-image-6" />[/caption] - if this one doesn't work for your theme but works for the default one then you need to check your theme functions. Obviously there is override. You should search for anything that has following wording "img_caption_shortcode"

Comment: Like I said, the code you've given me works. The problem im having is with whenever I upload and image and give it a caption and i press insert media, wordpress only outputs the image tag and not the caption short code into the editor. I've also checked to make sure the shortcode is included in the media.php file and it's there. I can't find it anything in my functions though..

Comment: as you've mentioned that it works in the default theme - check your new theme function - the issue is in there, also you may try to deactivate all plugins, but I am pretty sure something is overriding default shortcode in your theme.